Is a spin manifold automatically orientable and time-orientable?
I'm reading Hamilton's Mathematical Gauge Theory. He defines a manifold to be spin if the second Stiefel–Whitney class of the manifold vanishes (p. 379). Does this condition already implies that the manifold is also orientable (i.e., that the first Stiefel–Whitney class vanishes) and time-orientable?

I believe Hamilton is already (implicitly) assuming the manifold is orientable. Indeed, the standard definition of spin requires $w_1 = 0$ and $w_2 = 0$. There are non-orientable analogues of the spin condition, which go by the names pin$^+$ and pin$^-$ which are characterised by the vanishing of $w_2$ and $w_2 + w_1^2$ respectively.

@MichaelAlbanese That makes sense. Do you know of any references that discuss these generalizations?

There's a brief discussion here. You could also look at the paper by Kirby and Taylor mentioned there.

I think neither of these implications hold.
The Klein bottle $\mathbb{K}$ is non-orientable, but admits a nowhere vanishing vector field, which should force $w_2(\mathbb{K}) = 0$. (The tangent bundle splits as a direct sum of a trivial bundle $\varepsilon$ and a Möbius-like line bundle $\zeta$, so the Steifel-Whitney classes of $\mathbb{K}$ are the Steifel-Whitney classes of $\zeta$, and $w_2(\zeta) = 0$ because $\zeta$ is rank $1$.)
It should not be hard to generalize this construction to $n$ dimensions, if desired; simply glue the ends of $\mathbb{T}^n \times [0, 1]$ by some map that flips one of the coordinates on $\mathbb{T}^n$. I think the tangent bundle should similarly split as $\varepsilon^n \oplus \zeta$ for some pullback $\zeta$ of a Möbius bundle on $\mathbb{S}^1$, and so the second Stiefel-Whitney class must again vanish.
It should similarly be easy to put a non-time-orientable metric on these spaces: view them as quotients of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and descend the standard $(n, 1)$ metric such that the "flipped" axis is the timelike one.
